# What event can be used to detect when WinUI3 TeachingTip has opened or loaded

Tags: c#, events, winui-3

I am using a [TeachingTip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.teachingtip?view=winui-2.7) control in a C# WinUI3 desktop app.  It mostly works OK, but I don't seem to see any event that is triggered when the control has opened (loaded) or is opening.

The control properties let me add an OnLoaded event, but that is not being triggered.

Would appreciate any pointers on adding such a handler.  I note that the only listed supported events for this control are: ActionButtonClick, CloseButtonClick, Closed and Closing.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `Loaded` event for the `TeachingTip`'s root element:

```
<TeachingTip ...
    Title="..."
    Subtitle="...">
    <TextBlock Loaded="OnLoaded" />
</TeachingTip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response.  I had supposed it would be something like this, and I may end up doing that.  However, at the moment I'm using the PointerPressed handler for the element that opens the TeachingTip.  It's good to know there are multiple ways to skin this cat.

Best regards.